# I cant hide forms after i have proceeded with my login form

Tags: c#

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Wrong_Username_or_Password Wrong_Username_Or_Password = new Wrong_Username_or_Password();
        Missing_Password_and_Username Missing_Password_And_Username = new Missing_Password_and_Username();
        Main Main = new Main();
        if (e.KeyValue == 13)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            if (textBox1.Text == "Test" && textBox2.Text == "Test")
            {
                Missing_Password_And_Username.Hide();
                Wrong_Username_Or_Password.Hide();
                this.Hide();
                Main.Show();
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text == "" && textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                Missing_Password_And_Username.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                Wrong_Username_Or_Password.Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't hide the Missing_Password_And_Username form and the Wrong_Username_Or_Password form after i have proceeded with the login but i can hide this form and i don't know how to hide these two forms and i dont want to use showdialog to make the user close the form because i dont like the "ding" sound when you press outside the form.

Comment: They dont have Close button or OK button? On click of them cant you write code to close them?

Comment: Why are you are running that code on every keypress?  The name and/or PW will always be wrong until they are done typing

Comment: The form that appears have an OK button that closes the form but the problem is that if they don't close the form and they login while the form is still showing it will show while the main form is showing and it looks weird to me.

Comment: @MarkusStone: Your expalantion does not make a lot of sense. Somethings seems to be very wrong with your design. You might have run into a XY Problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I will try to explain. I have a login form where i have two textboxes textbox1 for username and textbox2 for password. I also have two forms instead of messagboxes to show when something is wrong with the login. Because i think my custom form with the message "Wrong Username or Password" looks better than showing a messagebox with the message "Wrong Username or Password" but when the user logs in with the username "Test" and password "Test" the main form appears and the login form dissappears but my custom "Wrong Username or Password" form doesn't dissappear which i need help to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, the Problem is that you create on every keypress new instances of the forms **Wrong_Username_or_Password** and **Missing_Password_and_Username**. If you have shown one of those form instances during the last keypress event, you will have lost track of them during the current keypress event (since they have just been created and overwritten the respective local form variables). You are actually trying to hide forms you have never shown.

Move the form variables and their initializations out of the keypress event handler and make them local to the this-Form. This should solve it.